Pilas en arreglos y Colas y colas dobles en arreglos
Buen día, estoy realizando un programa referente al siguiente problema:
Descripción
Acabas de organizar una enorme fiesta con mil invitados (convenientemente numerados del 0 al 999) y la mayor atracción de la fiesta son los deliciosos tamales. Los invitados a la fiesta deben formarse en la cola y al llegar su turno, la señora de los tamales les dará un tamal. Como los tamales están verdaderamente ricos, muchos de los invitados vuelven a formarse en la cola. Sin embargo, la señora sólo tiene permitido darte un tamal a cada invitado (por cuestiones de presupuesto y para evitar que alguien se quede sin el suyo). Escribe un programa que ayude a la señora a identificar a qué invitados sí debe entregales un tamal cuando llegue su turno.
Entrada
Un entero N seguido de la descripción de N eventos. Los eventos pueden ser de dos tipos:

FORMA K: se formó el invitado con número K.
ATIENDE: la señora debe atender al invitado al frente de la cola.
Puedes suponer que 0 <= N <= 10^(4), que el número de cada invitado es válido, que los invitados se formarán sólo si en ese momento no están en la cola y que sólo se atenderá a un invitado si la cola no está vacía.

Salida
Para cada evento del tipo ATIENDE, imprimir el mensaje SI TAMAL o NO TAMAL seguido del número del invitado, dependiendo si la señora le debe entregar o no un tamal.
Utilicé la implementación de una cola utilizando un arreglo para el manejo de los invitados que se forman en la cola. Implementé una cola utilizando un arreglo y sus operaciones básicas como insertar, frenteCola y eliminar.
La cuestión es que la salida que me requiere la plataforma es distinta a la que me da mi programa:

Mi salida es la siguiente:

Mi código es el siguiente, puede que hiciera mucho código bruto, pero apenas estoy comprendiendo el tema, pero no se que me falla en mi salida, les agradecería su ayuda.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Definición del tamaño máximo de invitados
const int MAX_INVITADOS = 1000;

// Implementación de una cola utilizando un arreglo
class Cola {
private:
    int frente; // Índice del frente de la cola
    int final; // Índice del final de la cola
    int elementos[MAX_INVITADOS]; // Arreglo para almacenar los elementos de la cola

public:
    // Constructor
    Cola() {
        frente = -1; // Inicializar el frente de la cola como -1 (cola vacía)
        final = -1; // Inicializar el final de la cola como -1 (cola vacía)
    }

    // Método para verificar si la cola está vacía
    bool vacia() {
        return frente == -1; // La cola está vacía si el frente es -1
    }

    // Método para insertar un elemento en la cola
    void insertar(int invitado) {
        // Verificar si la cola está llena
        if (final == MAX_INVITADOS - 1) {
            return; // No se puede insertar más elementos, la cola está llena
        }
        // Si la cola está vacía, actualizar el frente
        if (frente == -1) {
            frente = 0;
        }
        // Incrementar el índice del final y agregar el invitado al final de la cola
        final++;
        elementos[final] = invitado;
    }

    // Método para obtener el elemento del frente de la cola
    int frenteCola() {
        // Verificar si la cola está vacía
        if (frente == -1) {
            return -1; // La cola está vacía, no hay elemento en el frente
        }
        // Devolver el elemento del frente de la cola
        return elementos[frente];
    }

    // Método para eliminar el elemento del frente de la cola
    void eliminar() {
        // Verificar si la cola está vacía
        if (frente == -1) {
            return; // No se puede eliminar, la cola está vacía
        }
        // Si solo hay un elemento en la cola, actualizar tanto el frente como el final
        if (frente == final) {
            frente = -1;
            final = -1;
        } else {
            // Si hay más de un elemento en la cola, solo actualizar el frente
            frente++;
        }
    }
};

// Implementación de un conjunto utilizando un arreglo y hashing simple
class Conjunto {
private:
    bool elementos[MAX_INVITADOS]; // Arreglo para almacenar los elementos del conjunto

public:
    // Constructor
    Conjunto() {
        // Inicializar todos los elementos del conjunto como falso
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_INVITADOS; ++i) {
            elementos[i] = false;
        }
    }

    // Método para insertar un elemento en el conjunto
    void insertar(int invitado) {
        elementos[invitado] = true; // Marcar el elemento como presente en el conjunto
    }

    // Método para buscar un elemento en el conjunto
    bool buscar(int invitado) {
        return elementos[invitado]; // Devolver verdadero si el elemento está presente en el conjunto
    }
};

// Función principal
int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N; // Leer el número de eventos

    // Declaración de objetos de Cola y Conjunto
    Cola cola;
    Conjunto enCola;
    Conjunto atendidos;

    vector<string> salida; // Vector para almacenar los mensajes de salida

    // Procesar cada evento
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        string evento;
        cin >> evento; // Leer el tipo de evento

        if (evento == "FORMA") {
            int invitado;
            cin >> invitado; // Leer el número del invitado

            // Verificar si el invitado ya está en la cola o ya ha sido atendido
            if (!enCola.buscar(invitado) && !atendidos.buscar(invitado)) {
                cola.insertar(invitado); // Insertar al invitado en la cola
                enCola.insertar(invitado); // Marcar al invitado como presente en la cola
            }
        } else if (evento == "ATIENDE") {
            if (!cola.vacia()) {
                int invitado = cola.frenteCola(); // Obtener el invitado del frente de la cola
                cola.eliminar(); // Eliminar al invitado del frente de la cola

                // Verificar si el invitado ya ha sido atendido
                if (!atendidos.buscar(invitado)) {
                    salida.push_back("SI TAMAL " + to_string(invitado)); // Agregar mensaje de "SI TAMAL" al vector de salida
                    atendidos.insertar(invitado); // Marcar al invitado como atendido
                } else {
                    salida.push_back("NO TAMAL " + to_string(invitado)); // Agregar mensaje de "NO TAMAL" al vector de salida
                }
            } else {
                salida.push_back("NO TAMAL"); // Agregar mensaje de "NO TAMAL" al vector de salida si la cola está vacía
            }
        }
    }

    // Imprimir los mensajes de salida
    for (const auto& mensaje : salida) {
        cout << mensaje << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


A simple vista, no estas agregando a la cola el invitado en el caso de que este ya hubiera estado en ella antes. El segundo FORMA 9 no agrega el invitado a la cola, por lo que el siguiente ATIENDE pasa al 2.

El problema es que tu condición para formar a un invitado en la cola es:
if (!enCola.buscar(invitado) && !atendidos.buscar(invitado))

Esto implica que si un invitado a sido ya atendido, no lo agregas a la cola. Por lo que el else de:
if (!atendidos.buscar(invitado)) {
    ...
} else {
    salida.push_back("NO TAMAL " + to_string(invitado)); 
}

jamás llegará a ejecutarse, simplemente porque nunca agregas un invitado a la cola que hubiera estado antes, el if siempre es cierto.
En el ejemplo, al llegar al segundo FORMA 9, como el invitado 9 fue atendido antes no lo agregas a la cola, esto implica que después del FORMA 2 tu cola es 0 << 2 no 0 << 9 << 2, por lo que las salidas de los tres últimos tres ATIENDE se corresponden con "Si tamal 0", "Si tamal 2" y "No tamal" (cola vacía).
Siguiendo tu lógica deberías hacer dos cambios:

Agregar el invitado a la cola independientemente de si ya recibió su tamal, es decir, cambiar:
if (!enCola.buscar(invitado) && !atendidos.buscar(invitado))

por simplemente:
if (!enCola.buscar(invitado))


Debes eliminar de enCola al invitado cuando lo hagas de cola. Deberías agregar un método a tu clase Conjunto para ello:
void eliminar(int invitado) {
    elementos[invitado] = false;
}

y luego:
 } else if (evento == "ATIENDE") {
      if (!cola.vacia()) {
          int invitado = cola.frenteCola();
          cola.eliminar();
          enCola.eliminar(invitado); // <<<<<<<



No obstante, si no lo he malinterpretado, el ejercicio especifica que puedes asumir:

"que los invitados se formarán sólo si en ese momento no están en la cola"

"que sólo se atenderá a un invitado si la cola no está vacía"


Por lo que en principio no necesitarías enCola ni comprobar si la cola está vacía.
int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N; // Leer el número de eventos

    // Declaración de objetos de Cola y Conjunto
    Cola cola;
    Conjunto atendidos;

    // Procesar cada evento
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        string evento;
        cin >> evento; // Leer el tipo de evento

        if (evento == "FORMA") {
            int invitado;
            cin >> invitado; // Leer el número del invitado
            cola.insertar(invitado); // Insertar al invitado en la cola

        } else if (evento == "ATIENDE") {
            int invitado = cola.frenteCola(); // Obtener el invitado del frente de la cola
            cola.eliminar(); // Eliminar al invitado del frente de la cola

            // Verificar si el invitado ya ha sido atendido
            if (!atendidos.buscar(invitado)) {
                cout << "SI TAMAL " << to_string(invitado) << endl; 
                atendidos.insertar(invitado);
            } else {
                cout << "NO TAMAL " << to_string(invitado) << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

No entro en la implementación de tus estructuras de datos ya que no es parte del problema planteado y para no extender la respuesta, pero hay otras formas más optimas suponiendo que no quieras hacer uso de la STL. Por ejemplo, las colas típicamente se implementan simplemente mediante una estructura/clase que represente un nodo, con al menos dos campos, uno para almacenar el valor y  otro que mantenga una referencia al siguiente nodo en la lista.
